# Update every second to display time

Tags: javascript, time, setinterval

Im really new to this. I want this js to update every scond so it acts like a clock or to display time

Maybe using setInterval? I dont know how to do that

Here's my code

*Ignore the bahasa language on my code*

```
date = new Date();
 menit = date.getMinutes();
 jam = date.getHours();
 hari = date.getDay();
 tanggal = date.getDate();
 bulan = date.getMonth();
 tahun = date.getFullYear();

document.write(tanggal+" "+arrbulan[bulan]+" "+tahun+"<br>"+jam+" : "+menit);
```

Comment: yes, setInterval is what you want, and it is explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: A good place to start when you don't know how to use a tool is to check the documentation, then try it out. Once you have, we can help you debug it.

Comment: [requestAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)  [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)  [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

Comment: the problem is you have to increase your time each time the setInterval callback executes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<p id="date"></p>

<script>
setInterval(function(){
date = new Date();
seconds = date.getSeconds();
 menit = date.getMinutes();
 jam = date.getHours();
 hari = date.getDay();
 tanggal = date.getDate();
 bulan = date.getMonth();
 tahun = date.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = tanggal+" "+((bulan+1)%12)+" "+tahun+"<br>"+jam+" : "+menit+" : "+seconds;
},1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `setInterval` would be the way.

What you need is to wrap your code that generates the date in:

```
    setInterval(function() {
        // Load the date here every second
        document.getElementById('your-date-element').innerHTML = YOUR_DATE_HERE
    }, 1000)
```

Substitute `your-date-element` for the ID of the element where you want your date to go and `YOUR_DATE_HERE` for the date in the format you want.

This code will run every 1000ms (1 second) and update the date accordingly.

Comment: Will try tommorow

Answer (score 1):

Well,
you could target div in your html code with:

```
const myDiv = document.getElementById('myId');
```

and then use it to set it's inner text like this:

```
setInterval(() => {
  myDiv.innerText = myFunction();
}, 1000);
```

where *myFunction* is:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  date = new Date();

  menit = date.getMinutes();
  jam = date.getHours();
  hari = date.getDay();
  tanggal = date.getDate();
  bulan = date.getMonth();
  tahun = date.getFullYear();

  return tanggal + ' ' + arrbulan[bulan] + ' ' + tahun + '<br />' + jam + ' : ' + menit;
}
```

Comment: I will try this tommorow